# postgreSQL fill gaps with rows according specific date interval

Tags: postgresql, fill

Please help me to build a proper PostgreSQL query with filled gaps in data according time interval.

I have data set:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:00+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:01+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 11
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:02+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 10.5
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:05+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 11.5
    }
]

DB: 
╔════════════════════════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║           date             ║  name    ║ value ║
╠════════════════════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║  2022-10-09T10:00:00+00:00 ║ entity 1 ║  10   ║
║  2022-10-09T10:00:01+00:00 ║ entity 1 ║  11   ║
║  2022-10-09T10:00:02+00:00 ║ entity 1 ║  10.5 ║
║  2022-10-09T10:00:05+00:00 ║ entity 1 ║  11.5 ║
╚════════════════════════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

The time interval as you might see is 1 second.

Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:00+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:01+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 11
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:02+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 10.5
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:03+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:04+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-09T10:00:05+00:00",
        "name": "entity 1",
        "value": 11.5
    }
]
```

So I need to build a query with filled gaps for absent rows according the time interval, so we need to display rows with times 2022-10-09T10:00:03+00:00 and 2022-10-09T10:00:04+00:00.

I would be very appreciated for some example of the needed query or any kind of advice!

Comment: Each object is a row in the Db with 3 columns

Comment: Thx for advice, I've done it already

Comment: Does [this](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/) help?

Comment: No. All that information doesn't close my question about how to populate (fill) gaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
WITH RECURSIVE date_series (d) AS (
    SELECT min(date) FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d + '1 second'::interval FROM date_series
    WHERE d < (SELECT max(date) FROM tbl))
SELECT
    date_series.d,
    name,
    value
FROM
    date_series
    LEFT JOIN tbl ON date_series.d = tbl.date
ORDER BY
    date_series.d;
```

Replace `tbl` with your table name.